# Variables in a Package

Tags: packages

If I do this:

```
func1[x_List] := Apply[Plus, x];
func2[x_List] := Apply[Plus, x^2];
func3[x_List, y_List] := Map[(fun1[x] # - fun2[x] #^2) &, y];
```

`func3` takes 112s to compute. However, if I do

```
f1 = Apply[Plus, x];
f2 = Apply[Plus, x^2];
func3[y_List] := Map[(f1 # - f2 #^2) &, y]
```

it takes only 2 ms. It looks like `func1` and `func2` are evaluated for each element of `func3`.

How do I implement something like in the second example in a Package?

I have the following lines in a package:

```
sc[A_] := Mean[F[A]];
n[A_,k_] := sc[A] (k-1)/2;
S2[A_,k_,e_] := Map[(n[A,k] # + sc[A])&, S1[A,k,e]];
```

The package works but very slow.

```
sc = Mean[A]; (*computed only once*)
n = sc[A] (k-1)/2; (*computed only once*)
S2[A_,k_,e_] := Map[(n # + sc)&, S1[A,k,e]];
```

Doesn't work. I get

```
{{Mean[{}] - 
   0.48654 (-1 + MatchGrid`Private`k) Mean[{}][MatchGrid`Private`A],
```

It looks like `n` and `sc` has no meaning. How can I define variables in the private section of a package to hold values which need to be computed only once?

Comment: You are right, The function, given to "Map" is evaluated for every element in "y". Therefore, keep this function as short as possible. E.g. do not evaluate fun1 and fun2 in it, but use the result of fun1 and fun2. The same is valid for your second example. In your second example, you did not define "F and "S1".

Answer (score 0):

A working solution is to use a Module.

```
BeginPackage["myprobe`"];
  myprobe::usage="myprobe[M]";
  Begin["`Private`"];
    myprobe[M_]:=
      Module[{n},
        n=Min[M];
        Min[Map[n #+#^2 &,M]]
      ]
  End[];
EndPackage[];
```

This works and fast as I imagined.